# Is it possible to upload files for wordpress importer over FTP?

Tags: uploads

I run WordPress on Heroku – an environment where you can't upload files manually, but rather push them via Git. I host my files on `Amazon AWS Filebucket`.

This generally works great, however, I get an error when I try to import a WordPress XML from another WordPress site.

WordPress tries to upload the file and then read it, but this doesn't work as the directory is read only. I wonder weather I can put the file somewhere on the server so that it's there when WordPress tries to find it.

Comment: Set your permissions... [`chmod()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.chmod.php) for the rescue...

Comment: that's not the problem, the only way to upload files to the webserver is by committing to a git-repo

Comment: Why not commit & then [Add From Server](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/add-from-server/)?

Comment: Great idea, allthough, I can add files to the media-library (using a plugin that replaces local storage with cloud storage). The problem is that this approach doesn't work with wordpress importer.